# Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant yet got errors and not connected

Tags: linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant, void-linux

**i'm using #*Void_linux*. Before i was using *Ethernet*. I've never used *wireless* before...**

```
# ip link show

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp12s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:71:98:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wwp0s29u1u6i6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT
group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 06:0a:7e:d4:64:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**so i created a config file here :**

```
# touch /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwp0s29u1u6i6.conf
# vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwp0s29u1u6i6.conf
edition :
           1. ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
           2. update_config=1
(save & exit)
```

**and after done editing, i applied my wifi name and password into config file.**

```
# wpa_passphrase <ssid> <pass> >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwp0s29u1u6i6.conf
# vi /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwp0s29u1u6i6.conf

    ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
    update_config=1
    network={
            ssid="Wifi"
            #psk="01632413440"
            psk=84195e97272a26e42479c32d36e10eef82f347530aba8bd6ec2bc65dbe2fadd8
    }
```

**Here last cmnd,**

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -i wwp0s29u1u6i6 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwp0s29u1u6i6.conf
```

**and after that i got all this Errors output :**

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: Driver does not support authentication/association or connect commands
nl80211: deinit ifname=wwp0s29u1u6i6 disabled_11b_rates=0
wwp0s29u1u6i6: Failed to initialize driver interface
```

**Here i don't know what to do ? Please give me instruction,

***Thank you* :)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using wext driver

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i wwp0s29u1u6i6 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wwp0s29u1u6i6.conf
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wpa_supplicant#nl80211_driver_not_supported_on_some_hardware